# What kind of word is the "a" in "a few"?

Tags: grammar

What kind of word the the "a" in a sentence like "I left a few books in the office"?  Is this an indefinite article, even if "few" here does not seem to be a noun?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the world-renowned *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Huddleston & Pullum, 2002) the word *a* in the lexical determinative *a few* is indeed the indefinite article.

Note that *a few books* is completely different in structure from *the few books*, which looks similar but isn't.

Here is the relevant excerpt (p. 392):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reference!

Comment: Somewhat bewildering how _very_ does what you’d expect and intensifies the fewness expressed by _a few_, while _good_ and _fair_ (semantically similar to _very_) have the exact opposite function, turning the fewness into a maniness (manyness?).

Answer (score 0):

Simply an 'article' just like in any other use case. If I gave you a few books, and you'd put them away something, I could ask you:

```
"Hey, where did you put the few books I gave you?"
```

That would be correct English, even though it would be irrelevant to use 'few' in this instance.

Edit: 'few' is a numeral, not a noun. This is why it can be used independently, yet also as an adjective.

Comment: According to Wikipedia "[a]n article (with the linguistic glossing abbreviation art) is a word that is used with a noun (as a standalone word or a prefix or suffix) to specify grammatical definiteness of the noun, and in some languages extending to volume or numerical scope."  Would the noun in question be "books" here ("a ... books")?

Comment: *"This is because 'a' belongs to books, not to few."* No, "a books" is incorrect. The "a" belongs with ["few"](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/few).

Comment: It's a noun in [*We **few**, we happy **few**, we band of brothers.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St_Crispin%27s_Day_Speech)

Comment: "few" is an 'indefinite numeral', not a noun.

Comment: The [full OED:](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/69699?redirectedFrom=few#eid) **few** *adj., pron., and **n**.*

Comment: With the discussion, this answer has turned a bit into a mess.  @Tea_Lover_XXX, do you have a reference to support your theory that "a" is an article here?  I agree that "few" can be used as a noun, but I don't think it is used in this role in my example sentence.  I saw your edit, but I don't immediately see what this says about the role of "a".

Comment: **A few books** versus **a lot of books**. **A few x** and **a lot of x** are idiomatic usages. You cannot separate "a few" plus noun into a+few+noun. It's: a few (one semantic unit) + books (another unit).

Comment: *Few* is most certainly ***not*** a numeral. Both *one* and *1* are numbers. *One* is a word, while *1* is a numeral. But *Few* isn't even a number. It's both an adjective (modifier) and a quantifier (determiner).